# Displaying desired information in a combo box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create what I think is a simple access Database. Problem is that I am new to using access but familiar with programming and very familiar with working in Excel. I can technically and have already done the task in excel but what I really like about Access is the Forms. I would essentially like a user to use the form as they would my Excel document but since they would have limited control, there would be less room to mess up the process.

Anyways what I am trying to do is populate a field in a table with a number. However this number signifies a severity (e.g. 1 for low 10 for high). Each severity has a "map" or "gauge" that explains what the number means in severity (e.g. 1 - will not happen, 2 - rarely happens, 3 - sometimes happens, 4 - happens, 5 - always happens). What I would like to do is to have the user see from a dropdown list the number and associated severity meaning. Then what I would like to stay once selected is only the number.

Example case:
User wants to say that something sometimes happens. User clicks on the drop down list and sees this menu:
1 - will not happen
2 - rarely happens
3 - sometimes happens
4 - happens
5 - always happens

They click on the "3 - sometimes happens". Then what they see in the field that they have just edited "3".

I think this should be possible but I am unsure on how I would even go about this. I have only started with tables, I have not made queries or forms yet. I would eventually like the user to do this all on a form so that way they have limited access. For now I am simply trying to populate a table the way I think it should be made.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do something like this is to use a value list and then display two columns in the drop down but show only one in the combo box.

---

**Step 1**

Go to the Data tab of the properties. Set the combo box `Row Source Type` to Value List and then follow the below example for what to put into the `Row Source`:

`1;"Will not happen";2;"Rarely";3;"Sometimes";` etc

Make sure the `Bound Column` is set to 1

---

**Step 2**

Then go to the Format tab and set the `Column Count` to 2. Set the `Column Widths` below it to `1,3` or whatever size suits your system the best.

---

If you want to use data from a table instead of a value list it's a simple matter of writing a query to select the two columns containing the number and info like below:

`SELECT [Severity], [SeverityMessage] FROM TBL_SEVERITY`

To use this simply replace `Severity` and `SeverityMessage` with the relevant column names in your table and `TBL_SEVERITY` with the name of the table. Then place this line into the `Row Source` and change `Row Source Type` to `Table/Query`

---

That should now be you set up with what you're looking for.

Comment: So this looks like it will work but how do I populate with information from another table? Essentially I have a table already made with the proper wording of the various severities.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the option of using a table.

Comment: Actually I was able to figure it out. Turns out all the settings need to remain but it is possible to setup a Table/Query source and add the two columns needed. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If you feel my answer helped you could mark it as accepted to help others in the future.